# how can i group int then work out the highest number c#

Tags: max

I am building a program using visual studio C#.

I have a list of figures that are inputted into text boxes.

I need to make a calculation using the highest inputted figure and wondered how I would go about this.

I have been reading a lot of similar questions in this site but not got the answer yet.  I am new to programming and still 'self teaching' myself about the language so please go easy lol.

I have these int declared ads1, ads2, ads3, ads4, ads5, ads6

these figures are then taken from a text box (admissions1, admission2 etc.)

I need to calculate a sum using the highest admission number (i.e. the total amount of admissions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;
```

...

```
var arr = new int[] { ads1, ads2, ads3, ads4, ads5, ads6 };
return arr.OrderBy(i => i).First();
```

This uses the Linq extension methods `OrderBy` and `First`.